# The Sign of The Four

Tags: nouns

This book title is wellknown, but as an English learner, I can't understand why Conan Doyle wrote "The Sign of The four", instead of "Four Signs".
It might be more meaningful.

Though I knew "the four" means four people, I think "sign" should be added an "-s".
Could any kind person explain it to me?
I didn't find a webpage I need on the Internet.

Comment: Well, never read the book or anything about it, but isn't it possible that the "sign" related to four of something, rather than there being four separate signs?

Comment: The sign of the four men.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The sign of the four* is not four separate signs—it is a single sign designating the partnership of Jonathan Small, Mahomet Singh, Abdullah Khan and Dost Akbar.

> ... next day I drew four plans, one for each of us, and put the sign of the four of us at the bottom, for we had sworn that we should each always act for all, so that none might take advantage.

The actual 'sign' is never described in the story, but Small twice leaves a paper with the words "the sign of the four" to claim responsibility for his acts on behalf of the partnership, and he describes his final act, the scattering of the Agra treasure, with the same phrase:

> I tell you that no living man has any right to it, unless it is three men who are in the Andaman convict-barracks and myself. I know now that I cannot have the use of it, and I know that they cannot. I have acted all through for them as much as for myself. It's been the sign of four with us always. Well, I know that they would have had me do just what I have done, and throw the treasure into the Thames rather than let it go to kith or kin of Sholto or Morstan.

Comment: As pointed out in StoneyB's answer, there is a single sign so the OP's suggestion of "Four Signs" would be completely wrong in terms of the story. It is also grammatically wrong: "The X of the Y" means "The Y's X" rather than "The Y Xs." What is likely to have confused the OP is that the words for numbers are normally used as part of a noun phrase like "four apples." In the title, "The Sign of the Four," the noun expected after "four" has been omitted and so can be understood only from context, but the reader is not given any context. It is mysterious (as is desirable in a detective story.)